# Spring boot Axon complete rollback

Tags: spring-boot, axon, saga

How to rollback a transaction event which created data in database, I don't want to change status or anything, I need to rollback ( don't persist ) the changes. could any provide or suggest a way achieve this.

Comment: Are you looking to rollback the transaction of the event or the transaction of the updating data on the event handler?

Comment: Event handler. because if my event fails in the next handler, i want to rollback the changes done by previous event handler.

Comment: Ah, so you want subsequent Event Handling transactions to be tied to one another to cause a rollback, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Axon Framework will roll back operations to a database depending on the type of failure you're getting.

If the exception's thrown by the `@EventHandler` annotated method, the `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler` catches it. By default, this logs the message and proceeds. Differently put, the operation **is not** rolled back.

If you decide to rethrow the exception in the `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler` or the exception occurs during the processing of the event batch, Axon's `ErrorHandler` will catch it.
By default, the `ErrorHandler` rethrows the exception, causing the Event Processor to catch it. *This* will make it so that the event handling task is rolled back.

However, from your comments, it seems you're not looking for an Event Handling task to roll back on its own, but for an Event Handling task to roll back a previous Event Handling task. Note that from Axon's perspective, the Event **was** handled, so the change simply occurred.

If you want something like this to be undone, you could think about options like replaying altogether, adjusting the database yourself, and dispatching a compensating action. Whether any of those is the right fit is unclear to me as I am unaware of *what* you're actually trying to roll back for *what* reason.

Hence, I'd like you to provide a bit more background on what *your* exact scenario is, @ray. If you could please update your question with a description of the use case, that would be great.

In the meantime, here are some useful links from the Axon Framework documentation around Event Processing:

- [Event Processors](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors)
- [Event Processor Error Handling](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors#error-handling)
- [Streaming Event Processors](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors/streaming)